# Как сделать окно prompt, с двумя полями ввода?

Tags: javascript, input, prompt

Как сделать окно prompt, с двумя полями ввода?

Comment: никак, prompt системная функция, и не кастомизируется

Comment: prompt диалог содержит однострочное текстовое поле, кнопку Cancel и кнопку OK,  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: А какие есть варианты сделать что-то типо prompt, только с двумя полями?

Comment: Варианты есть изучить интерфейсы ui design - но это очень длинный путь!

Comment: Как вариант сделайте модальное окно, в гугле очень много статей и видео.

Comment: может быть два раза вызывать `prompt`?

Comment: рабочий кейс, через function (функцию)

Comment: создать свой `prompt`

Answer (score 1):

Никак. `prompt` - системная функция, и не кастомизируется.